# VBA Autofill error when last colomn is already filled

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code (see below) that finds if a column in the front of a sheet must be deleted when all the columns which needed to be deleted are deleted. the code finds the last used column and refills the sheet until it reaches column DO.

But now, when the column is already filled from the last time I pressed the button and no rows got deleted. the code crashes and says

> Error 1004 while executing. Methode Autofill of class Range failed.

It only works when the column DO is not used yet.

This is my code:

```
Dim lColumn As Long
Dim iCntr As Long

    lColumn = 20
    For iCntr = lColumn To 12 Step -1
        If Cells(3, iCntr) = 0 Then
        Columns(iCntr).Delete
End If
Next

With Workbooks("Bureauplanning2backup.xlsm").Worksheets("Planning")
Dim rngStart As Range
Set rngStart = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 
-1).EntireColumn

Dim rngEnd As Range
Set rngEnd = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).EntireColumn

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = .Range(rngStart, .Columns("DO"))

Dim rngX As Range
Set rngX = .Range(rngStart, rngEnd)

End With
rngX.AutoFill rng, Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Is there a way to check if column DO is already filled and when it is filled the code just does not run the line:

```
rngX.AutoFill rng, Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count how many cells in DO have data

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns("DO")) = 0 Then
    'zero cells have data so autofill
    rngX.AutoFill rng, Type:=xlFillDefault
Else
    'at least one cell has data so don't autofill
    MsgBox "Column DO has already data"
End If
```